# Onclick show div overlapping/hiding others

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, frontend

I'm trying to achieve 3 clickable `<div>` that expand and hide/overlap others on click, while showing what's inside each clicked `<div>`. I only have JQuery as of right now.

My initial question is, what should I use? (Flexbox? CSS animation? React?)
Is it possible in vanilla html+css+js stack without having a bonky transition ?
I made an image to illustrate what I'm trying to say:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is possible just by using pure Javascript, all you need to do is add a click event to each div, and when one is clicked you issue `yourDivName.setAttribute("style", "display: block");` and issue `yourDivName.setAttribute("style", "display: none");` to the other two. Then just repeat this process for each one. Obviously enclosing each one in a `function yourFunctionName(){
    //Enter logic here
}`

Your process should be first getting each div and putting it in a variable, then doing the above code according to what you wish to do to the div. I hope this helps let me know if you'd like me to do the Javascript for you :)

Comment: Thank you ! This will help my research ! I was scared of going the wrong way.
I will try to sort this by myself first and post the code !

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should write your script in the question when asking questions on [stackoverflow](https://www.stackoverflow.com). Because we must see what code do you have.

About your question, there are so many options. If you want to use jQuery:

HTML:

```
<div class="group"></div>
<div class="group"></div>
<div class="group"></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('.group').on('click', function(){
    $('.group').hide();
    $(this).show();
});
```

If you want to make it with CSS, you can do something like:

HTML:

```
<div class="group"></div>
<div class="group"></div>
<div class="group"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.group{
    display: none;
}
.group:active{
    display: block;
}
```

If you want to make some animation you can use [CSS transition](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp)

Comment: Thank you for your time and answer, working on it right now, i'll post the code later !
I'm sorry for the code, i didnt have any as i didnt really know where to start !

Answer (score 0):

I am answering my own question to show you the progress I made.
This is greatly starting to get form following both your advices. 
 (Jsfiddle at the end).

*HTML*

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>StackCode</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="dummy.css" />  
</head>
<body>
<header>    
</header>
<section class="section">   
        <div class="service-box">
                <div class="service-story">                 
                            <div> <h1> Title </h1> </div>
                <img class="img-left" src="https://via.placeholder.com/250x700">
                            <div class="service-story-expand">
                                <h1>TITLE</h1>
                                <p>Sample text</p>
                                <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100">
                            </div>                                      
                 </div> 
                 <div class="service-art">
                            <div> <h2> Title2 </h2></div>
                            <img class="img-middle" src="https://via.placeholder.com/250x700"> 
                            <div class="service-art-expand">
                                <h1>TITLE</h1>
                                <p>Sammple text</p>
                            </div>
                 </div> 
                 <div class="service-motion">
                            <div> <h2> Title3 </h2></div>
                            <img class="img-right" src="https://via.placeholder.com/250x700"> 
                            <div class="service-motion-expand">
                                <h1>TITLE</h1>
                                <p>Sammple text</p>
                            </div>
                 </div> 
            </div>
</section>      
<script src="jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="dummy.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

*CSS*

```
*
{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}

html { 
    overflow-x :hidden; 
    background: black;
}

header
{
  height:20px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: black;
    padding: 45 0 0 0;
    z-index: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

.section{
    width: 100%;
    background:grey;
    margin: auto;
}

.service-box{
  overflow: hidden;
    width: 90%;
    height: auto;
    margin:auto;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.service-story{
    height: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    flex:1;
    order: 1;
    transition: flex .3s ease-out;
}

.service-story.clicked{
    background:white;
    height: auto;
    flex:6;
    transition: flex .3s ease-out;
}

.service-story-expand{
    display: none;
}

.service-art{
    overflow: hidden;
    flex:1; 
    transition: flex .3s ease-out;
    order: 2;
}

.service-art.clicked{
    background:white;
    flex:6;
    transition: flex .3s ease-out;
}

.service-art-expand{
    display: none;
}

.service-motion{
    overflow: hidden;
    flex:1; 
    transition: flex .3s ease-out;
    order: 3;
}

.service-motion.clicked{
    background:white;
    flex:6;
    transition: flex .3s ease-out;
}

.service-motion.clicked img{
    float: left;
}

.service-motion-expand{
    display: none;
}

.service-story.clicked img{
    width:auto;
  height:auto;
}
```

*Js + Jquery*

```
$('.service-story').on('click', function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('clicked');
    $(this).show();
    $('.service-story-expand').show();
});

$('.service-art').on('click', function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('clicked');
    $(this).show();
    $('.service-story-expand').show();  
});

$('.service-motion').on('click', function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('clicked');
    $(this).show();
    $('.service-motion-expand').show();
});
```

I chose the solution of flexbox. This is not exactly what I was looking for, but it does the trick.
Now the problem I encounter are the following.

How to put content which is firstly hidden next to my images and not under ? 
How to close other divs when one is open ?
How to hide content once a `<div>` is clicked again ? (If I understand correctly, is a "If/Then/Else" situation) 
I think the last two questions are frequently asked, so I'll start searching by myself, just showing my progress.

Thank you once again for your time, and I hope I did better on formating.

Here is a jsfiddle.
https://jsfiddle.net/7oa28cg4/

Ps: Also working on responsiveness, i'm learning it.